# How to best model an "Array of collection" for Apache Beam @JavaBeanSchema and BigQuery?

Tags: java, json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Java class that models data meant for writing to both BigQuery and Elasticsearch. It looks something like this:

```java
@DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class)
// also lombok annotations for getters, setters, builder, constructors, etc.
public class DataClass implements Serializable {
  String field1;
  List<String> field2;
  List<List<String>> field3; // this one gives the compiler error below
}
```

We try to always use JavaBeanSchema.class for its nice compatibility with org.apache.beam.sdk.values.Row, com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow, and the org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.ToTableRow format function with org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO. Combining these things means we can use BigQueryIO.Write without any explicit schema or coders, minimal boilerplate code.

Compiling the above class into a Beam template results in an IllegalArgumentException "Array of collection is not supported in BigQuery." OK - fine, but we still need this class to model the data for Elasticsearch where this schema works fine in JSON.

I am looking for the simplest way I can do some version of what I need to with minimal code. The solution I currently have is creating a separate class `DataClassForBigQuery` that is essentially a copy of this one except `field3` is just a `List<String>` type, along with a `PTransform<DataClass, DataClassForBigQuery>` to serialize `field3` as a JSON string when they are created. This is a relatively small amount of code, a fairly isolated, but:

- I don't love the two classes to model the same data, just means more tests and maintenance
- BQ has a native JSON field type, with some support for querying the values. Since technically the BQ field type of `field3` is STRING, there's no good way to query/access that data without converting it to something else first. It would be nice if there was a way to annotate "this is a java String type, but interpret it as JSON".
- I tried modeling the POJO with more complex types to refactor/wrap the nested Lists into a List of Objects and each Object contained a List of Strings. I think this works for Big Query, but Beam wasn't able to build the template. I believe the error was a stack overflow trying to build the schema.
- If I could use the POJO class as-is, and somehow modify the schema on the fly to change the type of `field3`, and provide a function to format it but still leverage ToTableRow for the rest of it (the real class is large, 20+ fields), I'd try that. But I don't really want to extend org.apache.beam code to this, that would end up being more work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Consider avoiding a list of lists by introducing an intermediate type to hold the inner list:

```
@DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class)
public class MyIntermediateType implements Serializable {
  List<String> innerField;
}

@DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class)
// also lombok annotations for getters, setters, builder, constructors, etc.
public class DataClass implements Serializable {
  String field1;
  List<String> field2;
  List<MyIntermediateType> field3;
}
```

BigQuery will be able to represent this without further processing (`field3` becomes a repeated `STRUCT` that has one field that is a repeated `STRING`). I hope that Elasticsearch would also be able to interpret this structure, but I don't know details of Elasticsearch ingestion.

Comment: I had a problem with this approach and the Beam template not compiling. The error was a very vague stack overflow that appeared to be whatever the JavaBeanSchema does to figure out the schema. It might have something to do with my real data class having a lot more going on than my example. In fairness I didn't dig too deep in this direction, it might be a solvable problem.